# rails helper recursive block strange behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view-helpers

Following code should accept nested code and yield in 'li' tag

```
def sidebar_link(text,link, color = nil)
  recognized = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(link)
  output = ""
  content_tag(:li, :class => ( "sticker sticker-color-#{color}" if color) ) do
  if recognized[:controller] == params[:controller] && recognized[:action] == params[:action]
    output << link_to( text, link, :class => 'lead')
  else
    output << link_to( text, link) 
  end
  output << yield if block_given?
  raw output
 end
end
```

in HAML view:

```
      %ul
        = sidebar_link 'Tickets', tickets_path, :orange do
          %ul.sub-menu
            = sidebar_link "Service Requests #{ServiceRequest.all.count}", service_requests_path
        = sidebar_link 'Problems', problems_path, :green
        %li.divider
        = sidebar_link 'Clients', clients_path, :blueDark
        = sidebar_link  'Services', services_path, :red do
          %ul.sub-menu
            = sidebar_link 'Categories', categories_path
```

This produces correct HTML except first link. Output does not contain "Tickets" word,  but everything else seems to be fine.

So why this strange behaviour can occure? Helper recursion messes "output" variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution to explicit use &block as following

```
def sidebar_link(text,link, color = nil, &block)
 recognized = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(link)
 output = ""
 content_tag(:li, :class => ( "sticker sticker-color-#{color}" if color) ) do
  output << link_to( text, link, :class => ( 'lead' if recognized[:controller] == params[:controller] && recognized[:action] == params[:action]) )
  output << capture(&block) if block_given?
  raw output
 end
end
```